# Where is /pg_log/ in postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to trace the slow queries. I'm new to Pg9.6.
I could not find the /pg_log/ folder in the new version. It was available in /data/pg_log/ in older versions(I was using 9.2)..

If this is a repeating question, please tag.

Answer (score 2):

connect to your postgres and run:

```
 t=# show log_directory;
 log_directory
---------------
 pg_log
(1 row)

t=# show logging_collector ;
 logging_collector
-------------------
 on
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-logging.html

> log_directory (string)
>
> When logging_collector is enabled, this parameter determines the
>   directory in which log files will be created. It can be specified as
>   an absolute path, or relative to the cluster data directory. This
>   parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server
>   command line. The default is pg_log.

You could also want to check all not default values with

```
select name,setting from pg_settings where source <>'default' and name like 'log%';
```

Comment: `log_destination` is also an important setting in this context.

Comment: yes, I mentioned logging_collector because by default its off. and log_destination by default is stderr, so should be picked up by logging_collector. Do you think  I should include log_destination to the answer?